# Using kafka as a framework to search for information

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have a question about Apache Kafka. I have a scenario where I want to find information in a large 6GB .xml file, which is the latest dump of wikipedia. As such, it contains logical collections of information, generally spanning 20-25 lines. My goal is to have names of 2 football players as input, and search through this document additional information (which is present there) and compare them. Since I will need to parse through the document every time new names are entered, I am considering a sequential search and regex pattern matching. Later maybe experiment with indexing and inverse indexing. For a start my input file will contain about 100 000 lines.

I know the general concept of how Kafka works. There are servers which work as storage and other servers that are in charge of exporting and importing information. Then there are clients that can access this data and process it. My question is since this is just a school project, is there a point in me using kafka to process the input 6GB file? I have a simple demo running where I open and read a file in python and send it using a kafka producer and then "receive" it using a kafka consumer, but I am confused if it is not simpler to just read lines of the file as I go and look for the information I want.

Comment: Kafka won't help here. It's designed to support processing of large numbers of small messages. Typically the maximum message size is 1MiB. If, however, the file is actually comprised of lots of small messages, it might be a useful exercise to send them through as individual messages to have a play with Kafka partitioning, consumer groups and parallel processing in general.

Comment: If this is any help, the file is the latest xml dump of wikipedia, so it is comprised of small messages. E.g. a logical collection of information spans maybe 20 lines or so.

Comment: Then considering this is a school project, I would definitely consider splitting it up and sending individual message in. Depending on what processing you are doing, you may be able to do some in parallel before obtaining some final result.

Comment: I need to look up names of 2 football players and compare some of their information, implying I have to do a sequential search and do regex pattern matching. But I am still confused, can a producer send messages in parallel? I know that a consumer can use multithreading or be assigned to a particular topic partition, but the question is, is it faster than doing it regularly?

Comment: Ok, seems sensible. Why don't you add the extra detail to the question and I will try to come up with an answer which helps you to make a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka supports parallell processing by virtue of enabling topics to be split into partitions. In your case, I would consider creating a topic and splitting it into, say 50 partitions to begin with. You can then write records to the topic in quick succession from a single threaded process processing the xml.

Create a consumer that reads from the topic and performs the search; consider maybe outputting matching records to a final topic that your client can read from.

Instead of multi-threading the consumer (using *in*-process threading), you can just start multiple isolated instances of it, as long as you configure them to all join the same consumer group. Have your producer round robin records (this is done automatically as long as each record has a unique key -- you could use a uuid if you have no natural key). As you bring up more instances of the consumer, the kafka brokers will ensure that each picks up a roughly equal subset of the partitions and so you get a sensible load balancing effect. You should find that performance increase as you increase the number of consumer processes up to the number of cores you have available to perform the search.

By having the process which produces records to the input topic in the first place also await a result on the final output topic, you can easily write the result to the same tty as that which you use to launch to initial processing.

Starting multiple separate processes in the consumer group mimics the pattern of horizontal scaling in a distributed system. For example, in kubernetes, you can increase the number of replicas of a deployment (/replicaset) and if you are using kafka in the above manner, you will see a similar load balancing behaviour.